# Shows warning: Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      try {
                        final newUser =
                            await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email.text, password: password.text);
                        if (newUser != null) {
                          // Navigator.push(
                          //     context,
                          //     MaterialPageRoute(
                          //       builder: (context) => DashboardScreen(),
                          //     ));
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dashboard');
                        }

                        setState(() {});
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    }
                  },
```

this warning shown on Navigator.pushNamed(context,'dashboard');
trying to navigate to the dashboar screen.

[image]

Comment: Are you putted this method inside the build method?

Comment: If you click right there where it says "documentation", it'll take you to the page that has the answer to your question.

Comment: It happens because you are inside async function. add   if (!mounted) return; before Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dashboard');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**
You have to put delay for other process can finish till then

```
 Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200)).then((value) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dashboard')
});
```

**2.**
add `if (!mounted) return;` before `Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dashboard')`

**3.**
Please put await before the navigator flutter because you used an asynchronously method call so you have to wait until the process is finished then you can navigate to your pages

```
 await Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dashboard');
```

**4.**
Also, you can store your `navigator` into a `var` and then use it.

```
 final nav = Navigator.of(context);
 nav.pushNamed('dashboard');
```